# How to share twitter user credentials between web and mobile applications?

Tags: twitter, webservice-client, twitter-oauth, mobile-application, xauth

Our web allows the user to publish tweets in his timeline automatically when he does some particular actions. However, a mobile app is connected with the web, an sometimes some actions the user does in the mobile app must be sent to the web app so it publish the correspondly tweet in the user timeline.

The problem is that the user can signin or login in the mobile app using Twitter and the user credentials must be sent to the webapp so it is able to publish in the user timeline.

Which is the best approach to share the user credentials between the mobile app and the web app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to share your mobile app's access token with server, this is legal and works unless

> the utilization of the access tokens is based on the same agreement the user gave you

That's an official answer from thread https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4314. Another great citation from there:

> Access tokens represent the relationship between a user account and application -- the IP address or host of the machine involved isn't relevant.